# How can I get a button next to a dropdown using Tailwind?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I want to get this button to align next to the dropdown but couldn't figure out how since right now the button is below the dropdown

[What I mean by dropdown and button not aligning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7ba0.png)

Here's what I have code-wise - any help is appreciated!

> 

```
              <div class="items-center w-full">
                <%= form_for user_submission do |f| %>
                 <select id="user_submission_status" name="user_submission[status]" class=" mt-2 block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
                    <option selected>Pending</option>
                    <option>Approve</option>
                    <option>Reject</option>
                  </select> 
                  <!-- <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'text-white bg-primary hover:bg-primary-hover focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm p-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center me-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800' %> -->
                  <%= button_tag( :class => "text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm p-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center me-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800") do %>
                    <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 10">
                      <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 5h12m0 0L9 1m4 4L9 9"/>
                    </svg> 
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </td>
```

I've tried using flex and grid but still a noob so not quite sure how they interact here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<form>` wrapping your `select` and `button` needs to be a flex container. You also need to move the classes from the wrapping div to your form, like so:

```
<%= form_for user_submission, html: { class: 'flex items-center w-full' } do |f| %>
  <!-- Form content -->
<% end %>
```

I also noticed you have `mt-2` on your select. This will prevent the select and button from properly aligning vertically, so I suggest removing it. [This is a working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/AzSSNUoGLQ).

Comment: ah awesome it worked thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked! If this met your needs, feel free to [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)